# How can I use XPath with several attribute values?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm fine when I try to filter an XML result by attribute value, when it's in single form, but I want to pass an array of values, and for it to return elements that match this.

So this works as a single:

```
return get_reader_xml()->xpath("/ReaderDetails/Reader[Status='Available']");
```

But If I change the value to an array, like below, I get a syntax error message.

```
return get_reader_xml()->xpath("/ReaderDetails/Reader[Status=('Available', 'Busy')]");
```

Obviously I know what syntax error is, but everything I've read up on seems to suggest you can give comma separated values here... what mistake am I making?

Answer (score 1):

```
return get_reader_xml()->xpath("/ReaderDetails/Reader[Status='Available' or Status='Busy']");



return get_reader_xml()->xpath("/ReaderDetails/Reader[Status='Available'][Status='Busy']");
```

You could pass multiple parameters like above ways.

Comment: Hmm that's annoying, how could I easily loop that in PHP if I'm storing the value as an array? So I'm passing through `$options['Status']` which is stored as `array('Available', 'Busy')`. I can't so a simple implode, because I need to reiterate `Status=`

Comment: Try `"/ReaderDetails/Reader[@Status='".implode("' or @Status='", $options['Status'])."']"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a condition from the array. This can be done combining an `array_map()` with `implode()`.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<ReaderDetails>
  <Reader Status='Available'/>
  <Reader Status='Busy'/>
  <Reader Status='Broken'/>
</ReaderDetails>
XML;

$statusValues = ['Available', 'Busy'];
$condition = implode(
    ' or ',
    array_map(
        function($status) {
            return '@Status="'.$status.'"';
        },
        $statusValues
    )
);
$expression = '/ReaderDetails/Reader['.$condition.']';

var_dump($expression);

$details = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach ($details->xpath($expression) as $reader) {
    var_dump((string)$reader['Status']);
}
```

Output:

```
string(60) "/ReaderDetails/Reader[@Status="Available" or @Status="Busy"]" 
string(9) "Available" 
string(4) "Busy"
```